# Launching test SMTP server from ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, smtp

We are in the process of creating a training mode for our ColdFusion (9) sites.

The system will allow our users, after logging in, to switch from production mode to training mode by clicking on a link.

When they switch, the data-sources will be switched allowing the data to be safely modified.

We are also going to implement a test SMTP server, using the SubEthaSMTP Java project, in order to capture the emails that are sent from the training mode and display them to the user in a web page.

We can launch the SMTP server as a stand alone process or service without much trouble.

The nicer solution would be to launch server as part of the ColdFuson runtime at the point that the user switches to training mode.

We would create a true Java thread that would persist on a Server level scope for the length of any training sessions and then some arbitrary time out period.  If the server times out and a new training session is initiated we would initiate a new SMTP server.

My essential question is, therefore, is it a bad idea to run an ongoing thread in the ColdFusion runtime this way?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a problem with doing this, although you ought to test to see what resources SubEthaSMTP uses and make sure it's not going to cause you issues. It looks to have minimal dependencies (essentially just SLF4J, which ColdFusion 9 & 10 already provide)

From the [example page](http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/wiki/SimpleExample) it looks to be pretty easy to set up and drop into a long-running scope. I think you're right to pick the server scope, as you may have problems using application or anything more volatile, as there'll be a situation where application scope would timeout and be reset, but you'd loose all references to the Mail Server instance.

Please update the post with your findings, as I'd be interested in seeing what you find.